# Blur Theme mac os like?

Tags: themes, mac

Is there any mac theme with the blur effect, or how can i have blur effects in Ubuntu 16.04 I want it to look just like Mac OS sierra

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out some GTK themes over on [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/135/), or--interestingly--in a quick Google search, I came up with [this site](https://b00merang.weebly.com/gtk-themes.html) that develops emulated OS themes for Linux, including OS X. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks , But i am looking for the blur effect, Non of the themes from each site has blur effect, Thanks anyways ^__^